# MIAW (Messaging for In App & Web) Javascript for Image Resize/Compression

Tags: apex, javascript, community

As of Spring 23, the MIAW product does not offer image compression during upload. Our End users have low bandwidth and to preserve data storage in salesforce, I'm trying to seek a **javascript solution** that resizes an image before upload when the user attaches an image file and hits the send button in the MIAW conversation (Messaging Session). It will be in the **head markup** of the community.

My Challenge and current ask is with detecting the `event` as I do not see an ID associated with the send button in the embedded chat window so traditional way of dispatching onchange event isn't going to work. Trying to see what is the event for file attachment.
`event: 'force:attachment'` or `event: 'force:image'` ?

Here's a very official page:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/service/messaging-web/references/m4w-reference/event-listeners.html

Here's how a sample code looks like which clears the session on logout:

```
  window.addEventListener("onEmbeddedMessagingReady", () => {
        console.log("Received the onEmbeddedMessagingReady event…");
        if ($A) {
            $A.eventService.addHandler({
                event: 'force:logout',
                globalId: 'testLogout',
                handler: function (e) {
                    console.log("Received the force:logout event…");
                    // Clear previous chat session if it exists
                    embeddedservice_bootstrap.userVerificationAPI.clearSession();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Salesforce Product Support has acknowledged this as urgent and I will post an answer on 04/01 to this question.

Comment: how did you set up the user verification, as we need to pass the JWT token to head markup, we cant do the jwt creation in head tag js it will be at server side.
my approach is add dummy lwc which calls apex to generate jwt token , then lwc fires window event , which is captured by js in head tag and set embeddedservice_bootstrap.userVerificationAPI.setIdentityToken. it works , not sure this is recommended way or there are any better approach for this.

Comment: Our MIAW chat is used for Community Users, and is placed in an experience cloud site - login to this site is authenticated via an IDP (PingID) that enforces SSO and MFA, so we didn't have to authenticate a MIAW session via JWT or another such custom method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our expedited request to salesforce product team for MIAW, they were kind to include this as a feature in the platform. You must add this code to the head markup in the community.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> window.addEventListener("onEmbeddedMessagingReady", () => {
console.log("Received the onEmbeddedMessagingReady event.");
embeddedservice_bootstrap.settings.imageCompressionOptions = { maxWidth: 960,
maxHeight: 1280 };
});
</script>
```

maxWidth: The max-width of the output image. The value should be greater than 0.
maxHeight: The max height of the output image. The value should be greater than 0.
quality : The quality of the output image. It must be a number between 0 and 1. This option only available for image/jpeg and image/webp images. By default this is set to 0.8

Comment: Hi, did you set up User verification for MIAW ? Can I contact you to learn more on it ?

Comment: Our MIAW chat is used for Community Users, and is placed in an experience cloud site - login to this site is authenticated via an IDP (PingID) that enforces SSO and MFA, so we didn't have to authenticate a MIAW session via JWT or another such custom method.